# How to use the CSS :not selector for classes further up the DOM tree

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I have widget that has some styling applied to it. But then if a certain class is applied to the body that styling gets overridden. For example, let's say the body gets a class of `.blue-theme`

```
.widget { background: lime }
body.blue-theme .widget { background: blue }
```

This override will obviously apply to all widgets. Now let's say there's a type of page called `body.test`, where the same rules apply *except for one widget*, that has a class of `.joe`. This `.joe` widget can appear on other pages - but only if it appears on the `body.blue-theme.test` page does it ignore the overriding styles. I can achieve by overriding it again like this:

```
.widget { background: lime }
body.blue-theme .widget { background: blue }
body.blue-theme.test .widget.joe { background: lime } // revert to original styling
```

However in my case, I have many styles applied to the widget and it's child elements, so much so that it would be a huge headache if I need to make a change and have to change the styling in two places.

Is there some way, perhaps with clever use of selectors, whereby I can do this without that extra third line in my example? For example; saying that I want to override any widget in `body.blue-theme`, except for `.widget.joe` if the body also has a class of `.test`.

I am using LESS CSS, so a technique using that would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `:not()` allowed combinators, this would be trivial:

```
.widget { background: lime }
body.blue-theme .widget:not(body.test .joe) { background: blue }
```

But it doesn't in CSS, and there is no equivalent for `:not(body.test .joe)` that can be expressed as a single valid selector.

In your case, since `body.blue-theme.test .widget.joe` is more specific than `body.blue-theme .widget`, it is sufficient to move that selector into your first ruleset. It will override the second ruleset for those particular elements:

```
.widget, body.blue-theme.test .widget.joe { background: lime }
body.blue-theme .widget { background: blue }
```

Alternatively you could have two separate selectors in the overriding rule, one for all widgets in `body.blue-theme:not(.test)`, and one for all widgets except `.joe` in `body.blue-theme.test`:

```
.widget { background: lime }

body.blue-theme:not(.test) .widget,
body.blue-theme.test       .widget:not(.joe) { background: blue }
```

Either way, you will require at least two selectors in one of the rulesets. Personally, I find this method needlessly verbose compared to just combining the first and third rulesets together.

Answer (score 2):

This will do the job:

```
body.blue-theme.test .widget:not(.joe) { background: "blue" }
```

Comment: Thanks, the only problem with that solution is that it will only apply those styles to `body.blue-theme.test` and not to `body.blue-theme` as well. I need to ignore the styles for `.joe` in `body.blue-theme.test` but not in `body.blue-theme`.. and all other widgets should follow that style.

Comment: This rule will only ignore .joe in body.blue-theme.test, it will not ignore .joe in body.blue-theme

Comment: How about all other widgets in `body.blue-theme`? Would I need a seperate rule for them?

Comment: Yes you still need `body.blue-theme .widget {background: "blue";}` for that purpose.